# Альтернатива SUBSTRING_INDEX для MsSql

Tags: sql-server

Нужно выдернуть по 20 слов для анонса новости. Как это решить в MsSql?

Answer (score 1):

если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то использовать substring и charindex/patindex.

Comment: Есть поле fulltext, в котором хранится вся новость. Из него нужно выдернуть 10 слов для анонса...

Comment: Можете на примере показать? Че-то я не догоняю

Answer (score 1):

Привет.
Если нужно точно 20 слов. То придется вложить 19 раз поиск пробела.

Пример для трех пробелов:  text="аба абаа аббаа бааа ..... "

Решение: Charindex(' ', text, Charindex(' ', text, Charindex(' ', text)))

Далее: отрезаем с начало строки до пробела

Решение: Substring(text, 1, Charindex(' ', text, Charindex(' ', text, Charindex(' ', text))))

Но я бы порекомендовал использовать другой подход для анонса. По среднему количеству букв в слове 7.2 для русского языка. 20 пробел будет 20 * (7,2+1) получаем = 164 символа. 
Решение: Substring(text, 1, Charindex(' ', text, 164))

Все это при условии что существует 20 с лишнем пробелов.